# What can deep neural network be used for in control?

Tags: control-theory, optimal-control, neural-networks, linear-control, adaptive-control

I wonder if it's possible to use a neural network in control?

Let's say that we have a deep neural network:
$$a_i = \sigma(W_i*x_i + b_i)$$

That is trained from the inputs $u(t), r(t), \Delta u(t), e(t), \Delta e(t)$ and the output $y(t)$

I have created Deeplearing2C, which create a neural network into C-code.
https://github.com/DanielMartensson/Deeplearning2C

How can we use this deep neural network for controlling an object so its output $y(t)$ follows the reference $r(t)$

Any suggestions?

Comment: A suggestion: Perhaps defining your variables and providing a reference or two for context, will open your question to a slightly wider audience. I must admit I am not an expert in this sub-field, but I suspect this is more an engineering research and development question, than a mathematical question.

Comment: How is your training set created? If it is based on a (simpler) known control law then all the neural network will "learn" is an approximation of that control law, provided your training set contains enough and well distributed samples.

Comment: @JamesArathoon It's a control theory question - Applied math.

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen I don't know yet how my training is set. If you look at the software I have been created. Yet it works. I generate a neural network into C-code for embedded using BLAS libraries. Do you think a neural network can serve as a gian scheduling controller or a MRAS controller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your general question, check the proceedings of any recent controls conference, and you'll see a plethora of ideas of how deep learning (and machine learning in general) can be used in control. There is even a new conference dedicated just to this called *Learning for Dynamics and Control*, you may want to [watch the talks](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLYx2nCJDi_QFrGOmIM0ale8T_1Fqu8OIF). Most of them are very good. To see two radically opposed perspectives, start with the talks of Emo Todorov and Sergey Levine.

To be a bit more specific, take for example a non-recursive net with [ReLU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifier_(neural_networks)) activation functions. Each input-output path only goes through *affine* operations (multiplication and translation), though some paths can be shut off if they don't reach the activation threshold. In other words, you get a piece-wise affine operator from input to output.  Assuming your $x_i$ are all states, this would basically be learning gain scheduling for an affine full-state feedback controller. Change your states $x_i$ to errors, integrals and derivatives of errors, and you get gain scheduling for PID. Change your activations to something nonlinear, and you get nonlinear feedback, etc..

**Why would you do this?**
There are many reasons. Designing a gain-scheduler by hand can be tedious. You may also rely on incorrect models for your design, and wish to refine it from data. Or you may not have good models but a lot of data (e.g. a sewage network). Or you just want to ride the wave and get some publications.
How to make it track a trajectory? I would imagine augmenting your state with your desired state, or perhaps the error directly.

**Why wouldn't you do this?**
Again, many reasons. It is typically really difficult if not impossible to provide any guarantees for a deep neural network. Even when they work well, you don't know under what situations they will break down. Not having failure bounds is a bit scary.
Also, it typically takes a lot of training data to get good performance on a deep net. The practical ways of generating this data will often bias the training data and aggravate over-fitting.
And while deep learning is often touted around as "magic, it just works!", in reality it typically takes a lot of trial-and-error tuning of a lot of parameters. Just as for conventional control methods. So at the end of the day, if you *can* do it with conventional control approaches, you (imho) probably should.

**Mixing approaches**
One approach I've seen a few times is to design a controller with conventional control tools, and then train a neural net whose output is added to the control block, to account for un-modeled effects. If you can bound your neural net output, you should be able to keep some of the theoretical guarantees from your conventional controller.

Comment: You mean that a gainscheduler with PID is a good option ?

Comment: No, I just meant it as a clear example of what happens when you change your input, vs changing your activation function etc. There are a few cases where you know it will end up being equivalent to something with a very simple and clear equivalent from the classical control world. What might be a good option depends a lot on your system, what you want, etc.

Comment: So do you have any personal recommendations for a controller, based on neural networks?

Comment: @DanielMårtensson The question is why do you think you need a controller based on neural networks? I don't think its possible to give really useful recommendations when not even the objectives are clearly defined.

Comment: @SampleTime I think I need a controller based on neural networks because I am in need of nonlinear regression.

Comment: @DanielMårtensson Regression of what? What is your objective? Why do the standard adaptive/robust approaches not work? Useful recommendations will require more problem specific information.

Comment: @SampleTime Regression of a example hydraulic valve. Adaptive control is good, but it requires lots of knowledge of the process. In my opinion, adaptive control should be automatic, but it not 100% automatic. Robust control is not used so much. It's just experimental. I have a book about it, but a simple P-controller is much reliable and easier to tune in.

Comment: @DanielMårtensson I don't understand. If a simple P-controller works reliable for your problem, why bother to use a different controller? I also don't know what you mean with "automatic", but a neural network will certainly not work automatically. Quite the opposite, you have much more options to tweak there than in most other approaches.

Comment: @SampleTime Because am using deep learning to estimate a neural network model from data. 1. Collect data. 2 Estimate model 3. Implement model into embedded with C.

Comment: @DanielMårtensson That doesn't answer any of the questions.

Comment: @SampleTime I assume that you don't know if a neural network can be used for nonlinear control. Thank you for your time and answer anyway.

Comment: "So do you have any personal recommendations for a controller, based on neural networks?" No, I don't. I think it is extremely system-dependent, as @SampleTime also is saying, and also still a rather immature field of research. I don't think there are good general guidelines for it yet. I think it's a good topic for research, probably not a great tool for application yet.

Comment: I've added a small addition about mixing conventional controller design approaches and deep learning. You should search for this type of approach applied to systems similar to yours for more details. Also, from one of your previous comments, you mention what seems to be learning a dynamics model, instead of learning the controller. Both of these approaches are possible and can be effective, just make sure you're clear which one you're trying to do.